# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How do I fix an exception like:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

I want to do the table that can show the detail in period by using filter by date.

```
public void LoadSold()
{
        int i = 0;
        double total = 0;
        dgvSold.Rows.Clear();
        con.Open();

        if (cboSales.Text == "All Sales")
        {
            command = new SqlCommand("SELECT c.CartID, c.transno, c.ProductID, p.ProdDescription, c.price, c.qty, c.disc, c.total FROM tbCart AS c INNER JOIN Product AS p ON c.ProductID = p.ProductID WHERE status LIKE 'Sold' AND sdate BETWEEN '" + dtFrom.Value + "' AND '" + dtTo.Value + "'", con);
        }
        else
        {
            command = new SqlCommand("SELECT c.CartID, c.transno, c.ProductID, p.ProdDescription, c.price, c.qty, c.disc, c.total FROM tbCart AS c INNER JOIN Product AS p ON c.ProductID = p.ProductID WHERE status LIKE 'Sold' AND sdate BETWEEN '" + dtFrom.Value + "' AND '" + dtTo.Value + "' AND cashier LIKE '" + cboSales.Text + "'", con);
        }

        dr = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            i++;
            total += double.Parse(dr["total"].ToString());
            dgvSold.Rows.Add(i, dr[0].ToString(), dr[1].ToString(), dr[2].ToString(), dr[3].ToString(), dr[4].ToString(), dr[5].ToString(), dr[6].ToString(),dr[7].ToString());
        }

        dr.Close();
        con.Close();

        lblTotal.Text = total.ToString("#,##0.00");
}
```

Comment: Use a properly parameterized query, which will not only solve the problem of how to properly add values to your SQL commands, but also protect you against SQL attacks. Never form queries by concatenating together strings from user supplied values like this. It's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)According to my test, tymtam's answer is completely correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SQLParameter`:

```
var sql = ".... and sdate between @From ..."

var fromParam = new SqlParameter("@From", SqlDbType.DateTime);
fromParam.Value = dtFrom;

command.Parameters.Add(fromParam);
```